# Check if types are castable / subclasses

Tags: c#

I have they type of two members as strings - and not as a Type instance. How can I check if the two types are castable? Let's say string one is "System.Windows.Forms.Label" and the other one is "System.Windows.Forms.Control". How can I check if the first one is a subclass (or implicit castable) of the second one? Is this possible by using reflection?

Thanks for you support!

Comment: Where do these strings come from? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 22):

It might seem like you should use [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) but note carefully the documentation:

> `public virtual bool IsAssignableFrom(Type c)`
>
> `true` if `c` and the current [instance of] `Type` represent the same type, or if the current [instance of] `Type` is in the inheritance hierarchy of `c`, or if the current [instance of] `Type` is an interface that `c` implements, or if `c` is a generic type parameter and the current [instance of] `Type` represents one of the constraints of `c`. `false` if none of these conditions are `true`, or if `c` is a `null` reference (`Nothing` in Visual Basic).

In particular:

```
class Base { }
clase NotABase { public static implicit operator Base(NotABase o) { // } }

Console.WriteLine(typeof(Base).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(NotABase)));
```

will print `False` on the console even though `NotABase`s are implicitly castable to `Base`s. So, to handle casting, we could use reflection like so:

```
static class TypeExtensions {
    public static bool IsCastableTo(this Type from, Type to) {
        if (to.IsAssignableFrom(from)) {
            return true;
        }
        return from.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                          .Any(
                              m => m.ReturnType == to && 
                                   (m.Name == "op_Implicit" || 
                                    m.Name == "op_Explicit")
                          );
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(string).IsCastableTo(typeof(int))); // false
Console.WriteLine(typeof(NotABase).IsCastableTo(typeof(Base))); // true
```

And for your case

```
// from is string representing type name, e.g. "System.Windows.Forms.Label"
// to is string representing type name, e.g. "System.Windows.Forms.Control"
Type fromType = Type.GetType(from);
Type toType = Type.GetType(to);
bool castable = from.IsCastableTo(to);
```

Comment: `typeof(short).IsCastableTo(typeof(int))` returns `false`, even though `short` is implicitly convertible to `int`. Is there a way to make your method work for that case too?

Comment: Great solution. For completeness, I believe you should check m.ReturnType.IsAssignable(to) instead of checking equality. This means that you get implicit operators returning more derived types. A rare case but worth throwing it in there.

Comment: @Jason, there is a small issue here, where you should loop thru both types since cast operators can be defined on either type. Also as Gusdor says `IsAssignableFrom` would take care of casts possible via inheritance. Nevertheless an excellent starter. I will try to expand on it.

Comment: @Gusdor that's not a rare thing in my opinion. Thanks for suggestion, I made it an answer..

Answer (score 11):

I was helped by this discussion, Thanks.

I modified nawfal's code to solve problem about primitive types.

Now it returns correct results.

```
typeof(short).IsCastableTo(typeof(int)); // True
typeof(short).IsCastableTo(typeof(int), implicitly:true); // True
typeof(int).IsCastableTo(typeof(short)); // True
typeof(int).IsCastableTo(typeof(short), implicitly:true); // False
```

The code is as below.

```
public static bool IsCastableTo(this Type from, Type to, bool implicitly = false)
{
    return to.IsAssignableFrom(from) || from.HasCastDefined(to, implicitly);
}

static bool HasCastDefined(this Type from, Type to, bool implicitly)
{
    if ((from.IsPrimitive || from.IsEnum) && (to.IsPrimitive || to.IsEnum))
    {
        if (!implicitly)
            return from==to || (from!=typeof(Boolean) && to!=typeof(Boolean));

        Type[][] typeHierarchy = {
            new Type[] { typeof(Byte),  typeof(SByte), typeof(Char) },
            new Type[] { typeof(Int16), typeof(UInt16) },
            new Type[] { typeof(Int32), typeof(UInt32) },
            new Type[] { typeof(Int64), typeof(UInt64) },
            new Type[] { typeof(Single) },
            new Type[] { typeof(Double) }
        };
        IEnumerable<Type> lowerTypes = Enumerable.Empty<Type>();
        foreach (Type[] types in typeHierarchy)
        {
            if ( types.Any(t => t == to) )
                return lowerTypes.Any(t => t == from);
            lowerTypes = lowerTypes.Concat(types);
        }

        return false;   // IntPtr, UIntPtr, Enum, Boolean
    }
    return IsCastDefined(to, m => m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType, _ => from, implicitly, false)
        || IsCastDefined(from, _ => to, m => m.ReturnType, implicitly, true);
}

static bool IsCastDefined(Type type, Func<MethodInfo, Type> baseType,
                        Func<MethodInfo, Type> derivedType, bool implicitly, bool lookInBase)
{
    var bindinFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static
                    | (lookInBase ? BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy : BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
    return type.GetMethods(bindinFlags).Any(
        m => (m.Name=="op_Implicit" || (!implicitly && m.Name=="op_Explicit"))
            && baseType(m).IsAssignableFrom(derivedType(m)));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you can convert these strings to `Type` objects then your best bet is [Type.IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx).

Beware though, this only tells you if two `Type` instances are compatible at a CLR level.  This will not take into account such things as user defined conversions or other C# semantics.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
public bool IsCastable(String type0, String type1)
{
  return Type.GetType(type1).IsAssignableFrom(Type.GetType(type0));
}
```

Comment: It's important to note that this does not actually check whether or not the type represented by `type0` is castable to the type represented by `type1`. Your method will print `false` for class `Base { } class NotABase { public static implicit operator Base(NotABase o) { // details } }` even though a `NotABase` is castable to a `Base`. As the question asks to handle the case where an implicit cast is possible, I am downvoting.

Answer (score 4):

This is same as Jason's answer, but solves some problems with his solution.

```
public static bool IsCastableTo(this Type from, Type to)
{
    return to.IsAssignableFrom(from)
        || to.GetConvertOperators().Any(m => m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.IsAssignableFrom(from))
        || from.GetConvertOperators(true).Any(m => to.IsAssignableFrom(m.ReturnType));
}

public static IEnumerable<MethodInfo> GetConvertOperators(this Type type, bool lookInBase = false)
{
    var bindinFlags = BindingFlags.Public
                    | BindingFlags.Static
                    | (lookInBase ? BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy : BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
    return type.GetMethods(bindinFlags).Where(m => m.Name == "op_Implicit" || m.Name == "op_Explicit");
}
```

This should handle situations that arise due to inheritance as well. For instance:

```
class Mammal { public static implicit operator Car (Mammal o) { return null; } }
class Cow : Mammal { }
class Vehicle { }
class Car : Vehicle { }
```

Here the *implicit* relationship is between `Mammal` and `Car`, but since `Cow` is `Mammal` as well, there exist an implicit conversion from `Cow` to `Car`. But all `Car`s are `Vehicle`s; hence a `Cow` would go into a `Vehicle`.

```
Cow c = null; 
Vehicle v = c; //legal
```

So

```
typeof(Cow).IsCastableTo(typeof(Vehicle)); //true
```

prints true, even though no direct convert operator exist between `Cow` and `Vehicle`.

**The solution above fails for primitive types where the conversion is built directly into the language than the framework**, so something like

```
typeof(short).IsCastableTo(typeof(int));
```

fails. **Afaik, only manually handling will help. You will get complete list of [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx) and [explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b.aspx) conversion for numeric types and [other primitive types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx) from msdn.**

**Edit:**

The `IsCastableTo` function could be little more "[DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)" perhaps at the cost of being less readable, but I like it :)

```
public static bool IsCastableTo(this Type from, Type to)
{
    return to.IsAssignableFrom(from)
        || IsCastDefined(to, m => m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType, _ => from, false)
        || IsCastDefined(from, _ => to, m => m.ReturnType, true);
}

//little irrelevant DRY method
static bool IsCastDefined(Type type, Func<MethodInfo, Type> baseType, Func<MethodInfo, Type> derivedType, 
                          bool lookInBase)
{
    var bindinFlags = BindingFlags.Public
                    | BindingFlags.Static
                    | (lookInBase ? BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy : BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
    return type.GetMethods(bindinFlags).Any(m => (m.Name == "op_Implicit" || m.Name == "op_Explicit") 
                                              && baseType(m).IsAssignableFrom(derivedType(m)));
}
```

Comment: what do you mean dry?

Comment: Also, still doesn't solve the problem with int <==> short or long

Comment: @LouisRhys dry points to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself which I have updated in the answer. In my first answer, I'm using `IsAssignableFrom` functionality twice doing the same thing more or less. In the second approach I refactored that to a single method. It gets a little clunky there, but I like it better.

Comment: @LouisRhys I mentioned that in my answer. I updated it to highlight in bold. But you can handle it. Do some manual handling there urself by detecting primitive types. I posted two links where you will get the complete list. Do post that as an answer if you find the time to do it :) In my case I could safely ignore them.. I will update to cover that too if ever I get some leisure time in future..

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is value.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Control))
Basically, Type.IsSubclassOf method do what you need