# Can I cast an integer to a long when the types are generic/boxed?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

The method below looks for a particular key in a dictionary and attempts to safely store it in `destination` if it can.  The problem I am running into is when `T=Int64` and the item in the dictionary is `Int32` or `UInt32` (both of which can fit inside an Int64 without data loss).  `valueAsObject is T` returns false when T is Int64 and valueAsObject is Int32.

Is it possible to safely cast valueAsObject to T without just trying it and catching any exceptions?  I would like to avoid exceptions, though if that is the only way I can make it work.

```
public static void MyMethod<T>(IDictionary<String, Object> dictionary, String key, ref T destination)
{
    if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        return;

    var valueAsObject = dictionary[key];
    if (!(valueAsObject is T))
        return;

    destination = (T)valueAsObject;
}
```

Basically, I want the function to do nothing (return) if the thing found in the dictionary can not be safely stored in a type T variable (without data loss), otherwise it should cast it as necessary and store it.

Comment: why you not try to run it and find out the results, I am interested to know the results too

Comment: You can't do that, because you've boxed `Int32`, and you can't unbox it as `Int64`.

Comment: `long.TryParse(valueAsObject.ToString(), out value)`

Comment: I can't call TryParse on a generic like: `T.TryParse(...)`.  The purpose of the generic method is to make it so I don't have to write one of these functions for every type.  I could write an overload for all integer types I suppose, though that seems like it would require duplicating a lot of code.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1ybwb6z.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) also many value types implements interfaces like IComparable that can help to detect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final solution I went with.  It came from a number of comments and other answers so I encourage reading the other answers/comments for additional details as to why this was necessary:

```
private static void GetFromDictionary<T>(IDictionary<String, Object> dictionary, String key, ref T outputLocation)
{
    if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        return;

    var valueAsObject = dictionary[key];
    if (!CanBeCastTo<T>(valueAsObject))
        return;

    outputLocation = (T)Convert.ChangeType(valueAsObject, typeof(T));
}

private static bool CanBeCastTo<T>(Object thingToCast)
{
    if (thingToCast is T)
        return true;

    var tType = typeof(T);
    if (tType == typeof(Int64) && thingToCast is Int32)
        return true;

    if (tType == typeof(Double) && thingToCast is Decimal)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

In my case, I only needed to handle a certain subset of primitive types (Int32, Int64, String, Double, Decimal) and I was willing to accept lossy conversion of Decimal to Double.

The take away here is that the "is" operator will return false for primitives even if it can fit without loss (Int32 in Int64).  Also, `(T)valueAsObject` will not do an explicit typecast.  So if valueAsObject is of type Int32 and T is of type Int64 the above will throw an exception even though `(Int64)valueAsObject` is valid.  This one bit me but luckily @usr suggested using Convert.ChangeType which handles the problem.

Optimizations could be made to the above code but I chose to leave it as is for readability.

Answer (score 4):

This is not built-in at the language or runtime level. You can use `Convert.ChangeType` to perform the conversion. This method also performs lossy conversions so you probably have to build your own conversion logic (which will involve casts and be ugly).

Comment: Unfortunately I need something that will error if the conversion is lossy and support more than just integer types (for example, the dictionary might hold a complex object Foo cast to an Object.  The generic method needs to support casting the valueAsObject to Foo as well as to various integers.  Perhaps I can have check for each of the various numeric types and then call into another function that does the hairy work of checking to see where loss occurs but I am not sure how to detect a lossy cast.

Comment: @MicahCaldwell Will you be defining your own value types in your code, or will you only define reference types (classes)? The number of common value types in the framework is relatively low (a handful of signed and unsigned numeric types, and DateTime), so unless you're defining your own structs, or planning on using anything out of the ordinary, you might be able to just have a big switch or something that deals with all "possible" types. For reference types, your `is` line will work fine because there's no boxing involved.

Comment: That is what I am currently exploring.  First attempting to use the `is` operator which will take care of all reference types and then switching on all known value types and casting appropriately.

Comment: @MicahCaldwell Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119441/check-if-types-are-castable-subclasses

Comment: @MicahCaldwell what I try to tell you is that you indeed need to do all the manual work of switching on the types, avoiding lossless conversions and performing the allowed ones. This is not built-in. Not sure what else there is to tell you. Do you have further questions?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just do something like this?

```
public static void MyMethod<T>( IDictionary<string,object> dictionary , string key , ref T destination )
{
  object value ;
  bool   found = dictionary.TryGetValue( key , out value ) ;

  if (found && value is T)
  {
    destination = (T) value ;
  }

  return;
}
```

The [`is` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> evaluates to `true` if the provided expression is non-null, and the provided object
>   can be cast to the provided type without causing an exception to be thrown.
>
> .
>   .
>   .
>
> Note that the is operator only considers reference conversions, boxing conversions,
>   and unboxing conversions. Other conversions, such as user-defined conversions, are not considered.

Basically, if the object directly inherits from the specified type, or implements the type (if `T` is an interface), `is` should return `true` and you should be able to down-cast the object to your type `T`.

If, however, you need to worry about user-defined conversion operators, you'll need to reflect over the `object`'s type and over `typeof(T)` to see if a user-defined conversion operator is defined on either type that will convert the object to a compatible type. Getting that right is likely to be...tricky.

Comment: `value is T` in that example resolves to false when value is Int32 and T is Int64.  Also, I recently found that even if you get past that you still end up running into a problem of invalid cast exception if you try to typecast `(T)value` where value is type Int32 and T is Int64 (this one was particularly surprising).