# Check if (primitive) types are castable in C++

Tags: c++, casting, c++03

Is it possible to check (in C++), if types are castable (implicitly or explicitly)?
Is there something in the `std` or is it possible write a function like in C# ([C# same Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119441/check-if-types-are-castable-subclasses))?

I want to perform this check on *types* not the instances of the type.

I'm not sure about the type system in C++. Is there something like the `Type` class in C# or Java? `typeid(int)` was the nearest I found. Can I store a type to a variable? Closer reading tips will be appreciated.

At example:

```
bool isCastable(false);
bool withoutLoss(true);
isCastable = isCastableFromTo(typeid(int), typeid(__int64), withoutLoss); //true
isCastable = isCastableFromTo(typeid(int), typeid(short), withoutLoss); //false
isCastable = isCastableFromTo(typeid(int), typeid(double), withoutLoss); //true
isCastable = isCastableFromTo(typeid(double), typeid(int), withoutLoss); //false
isCastable = isCastableFromTo(typeid(string), typeid(int), withoutLoss); //false

withoutLoss = false;
isCastable = isCastableFromTo(typeid(int), typeid(__int64), withoutLoss); //true
isCastable = isCastableFromTo(typeid(int), typeid(short), withoutLoss); //true
isCastable = isCastableFromTo(typeid(int), typeid(double), withoutLoss); //true
isCastable = isCastableFromTo(typeid(double), typeid(int), withoutLoss); //true
isCastable = isCastableFromTo(typeid(string), typeid(int), withoutLoss); //false
```

Comment: static_cast, or for pointers dynamic_cast might help you, but it all depends on your use case

Comment: In C++ look at <type_traits> header (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/). You probably find std::is_convertible type trait useful.

Comment: there is also http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/bad_cast

Comment: <type_traits> is a nice tip, but we wan't not rely on C++11.

Comment: bad_cast is only thrown if I try to cast. But I want to check if a cast is possible based on types not instances.

Comment: This reeks of misuse of the C++ type system. Generally, casting is a code smell.

Comment: Yes it smells. but for some tasks it is better it smells than taking for ever.

Comment: I'm trieing to write a "littlebit generic" converter between a dynamic and a static Typesystem. Matlab and c++. I'm at the moment not sure how to design it "without" casting.

Comment: `<type_traits>` is the way to go. If you don’t want to use C++11 (why?!?!), re-implement this header by looking at standard library implementations. This will involve quite a bit of mindless copying and pasting, which is why you *should* really use the C++11 version.

Comment: @RobK, I disagree that "generally" casting is code-smell.  Does it get misused like many other facets of C++? Absolutely.  But to call it "generally bad smelling" is patently false! :)

Comment: Thanks! OK I will take a closer look at <type_traits>. I don't want to use C++11, because the mexfiles are a addition to a (algorithm) framework project, that should go open source. I don't want to push all users to C++11.

Comment: @GiCo: There is nothing wrong with C++11. Your code will not explode and the most common features are supported well enough for all major compilers.

Comment: @GiCo, you could be part of the movement to *push* users to C++11 :)

Comment: Is it possible to use C++11 in an existing VS 2005 project? This is for the potential users of the lib a commen situation.

Comment: @Moo-Juice: The users are in the mechanical engineering area. Some could be happy if they don't have to much trouble to use this lib. ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C++11 you can use `std::is_convertible` ([reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible)). This checks if an implicit conversion is possible. It does not consider if the conversion would be lossy.

---

Example:

```
#include <type_traits>
bool f_to_i = std::is_convertible<float,int>::value; // true
bool i64_to_i = std::is_convertible<int64_t,int>::value; // true
bool str_to_i = std::is_convertible<std::string,int>::value; // false
```

Answer (score 8):

This way:

```
template <class F, class T, class = T>
struct is_static_castable : std::false_type
{};

template <class F, class T>
struct is_static_castable<F, T, decltype(static_cast<T>(std::declval<F>()))> : std::true_type
{};
```

Comment: OP has explicitly restricted himself to C++03, see the comments under the question. Granted, the tag was missing (I just added it).

Comment: Note that this will not work in all cases (e.g. from `float` to `const int` will be false). See [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/s3tsgElYdpQd2z8o).

Comment: This is great to check whether a pointer `F*` can be assigned to a pointer `T*`.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the C++03 requirement, I propose

```
template<typename F, typename T>
concept static_castable = requires(F & v) { static_cast<T>(v); };
```