# Easy way to check if primitive data type "A" can fit safely into primitive data type "B" in c# (Assuming both are the same signedness)

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

Given this function:

```
bool WillDataTypeFit(Type typeToCheck, Type typeToFitInto)
{
    bool bWillFit = false;

    // Psedocode
    // IF typeToCheck is NOT the same as typeToFitInfo
    //    IF typeToCheck && typeToFitInfo are signed
    //       Check for signed fit
    //    ELSE IF typeToCheck && typeToFitInfo are unsigned
    //       Check for unsigned fit
    // ELSE
    //    bWillFit = true;

    return (bWillFit);
}
```

Is there a simple way to see if `typeToCheck` can fit safely into `typeToFitInto`?

I am concerned with primitive data types, excluding `DateSpan`, `DateTime`, `bool`, `decimal`, `string`, `char`, `object`

So basically `signed/unsigned int` and `float` and `double`

**EDIT:**

"Fit into" meaning I can safely convert the max/min value of `typeToCheck` to type of `typeToFitInto`, however at the time of this check I don't have any value to convert, so I am trying to simply check the data types

**EDIT2:**

I've realized that this question is generally flawed, since without a value you can't guarantee something like a positive `sbyte` fitting into a `byte`, I edited the question so the check is only evaluated if both data types have the same signedness

Comment: `C#`? Why are you tagging `C` ?

Comment: Must have clicked the choice too quickly, my mistake

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fit into"?

Comment: @RoadieRich please see my Edit

Comment: try { TypeA = TypeB.Default } catch { return can't} return can

Comment: Why the downvote? Something wrong with my question?

Comment: @Steve can you elaborate on your comment? Not sure what `TypeB.Default` is, `Type` has no `Default` property to access as far as I can tell

Comment: No, there is no such easy way in .NET already. You could create your own lookup table to determine this but you would need to do this yourself.

Comment: You would need to find a way to get the max and the minimum value for each type. If a precision is also counted, that would make it more complex.

Comment: default(typeToCheck)

Comment: @Steve the default for all the data types I need to check is 0, that wouldn't work

Comment: so by fit you mean the value would have to persist instead of just not throwing exception i.e. bool -> int ?

Comment: By fit I mean I can use a `UInt16` value as an input for a function that requires a `UInt32` value, or a `sbyte` value for a function that takes an `Int16`

Comment: I need to be sure that I can convert the maximum or minimum value of `typeToCheck` to the data type of `typeToFitInto`

Comment: then I think you are out of luck unless you are checking every single type

Comment: What would be the purpose of doing such tests as they would be slow and might not be as useful to know as you might expect since you can already ensure that value are in range on assignation? In most cases, selecting a type with a wide-enough range at both source and target fix the problem.

Comment: For the record, string and object are not primitive (value) types in C#.  They are types in C# which (why they can be all lower case), but they are not value types.

Comment: @Phil1970 I am working on a scripting engine DLL, the idea is to allow the user to use variables for command output data, and then potentially use those same variables as inputs to other functions. For the purpose of validation, I need to assure that a previously created variable of data type A can be safely used as an input to a function of data type B

Comment: If you check potential errors, then your system might be cumbersome to use. It would probably be more appropriate to only ensure that values are valid when calling a function. Usually a scripting engine care much less about types than say C#.

Comment: @Phil1970 these error checks are performed as the script is being parsed, prior to any execution logic, so I'm not necessarily THAT concerned with performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No easy way to do it that I know of.  You will need something like this:

```
bool WillDataTypeFit(Type typeToCheck, Type typeToFitInto)
{
    if (typeToCheck.Equals(typeToFitInto))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (typeToCheck == typeof(sbyte))
    {
        if (typeToFitInto == typeof(short))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(int))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(long))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(float))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(double))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(decimal))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else if (typeToCheck == typeof(byte))
    {
        if (typeToFitInto == typeof(short))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(ushort))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(int))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(uint))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(long))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(ulong))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(float))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(double))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(decimal))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else if (typeToCheck == typeof(ushort))
    {
        if (typeToFitInto == typeof(int))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(uint))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(long))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(ulong))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(float))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(double))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(decimal))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else if (typeToCheck == typeof(short))
    {
        if (typeToFitInto == typeof(int))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(long))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(float))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(double))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(decimal))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else if (typeToCheck == typeof(uint))
    {
        if (typeToFitInto == typeof(long))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(ulong))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(float))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(double))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(decimal))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else if (typeToCheck == typeof(int))
    {
        if (typeToFitInto == typeof(long))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(float))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(double))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(decimal))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else if (typeToCheck == typeof(long) || typeToCheck == typeof(ulong))
    {
        if (typeToFitInto == typeof(float))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(double))
            return true;
        else if (typeToFitInto == typeof(decimal))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else if (typeToCheck == typeof(float))
    {
        if (typeToFitInto == typeof(double))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I believe this is exhaustive for number types, but you can check here [Implicit Numeric Conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx)

Comment: I think this is probably the closest to what I was looking for. After thinking about it, I think the idea is just generally flawed because a positive `I8` value will fit safely into a `U8` variable, but you can't guarantee that without knowing what the value is. I probably need to at minimum limit the data types to the same `signed-ness`

Answer (score 0):

If you can limit your self to structs only, you can abuse the `dynamic` keyword to check.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(WillDataTypeFit<short, int>());
        Console.WriteLine(WillDataTypeFit<int, short>());
    }

    static bool WillDataTypeFit<TTypeToCheck, TTypeToFitInto>()
        where TTypeToCheck : struct
        where TTypeToFitInto : struct 
    {
        TTypeToCheck typeToCheck = default(TTypeToCheck);
        dynamic test = typeToCheck;
        try
        {
            TTypeToFitInto toFitInto = test;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using types like float, byte, etc. you could always use "sizeof." Consider:

```
Console.WriteLine(sizeof(bool)); // 1
Console.WriteLine(sizeof(byte)); // 1
Console.WriteLine(sizeof(short)); // 2
Console.WriteLine(sizeof(int)); // 4
Console.WriteLine(sizeof(long)); // 8
```

I can use Marshall.SizeOf for structs, for example:

```
private struct Temp
    {
        public int a { get; set; }
        public int b { get; set; }

        public int c { get; set; }

        public Temp(int a, int b, int c)
        {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
        }
    }
Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf(new Temp(1, 2, 3))); // 12
```

So you could use this to do your comparisons (depending on which types you're trying to compare; this'll definitely work for value types like structs, ints, etc. but it seems to break down for purely managed reference types; you definitely will *not* be able to do sizeof on a class like List because its size can't necessarily be known statically).

To address your question more directly, note that, in particular, sizeof(int) < sizeof(long) and sizeof(int) = sizeof(int), so they could "fit into" each other. In other words, *x* "fits into" *y* if, and only if, sizeof(x) <= sizeof(y)

Incidentally, for what it's worth, in this case "fits into" is an antisymmetric, reflexive, and transitive relationship, so it can be considered a partial order on .NET types. (It's not a total order because it doesn't order reference types).

Comment: Interesting idea, except that the size by itself doesn't guarantee the acceptable range of values. Example: `int` and `uint` have the same size, but not all `ints` (e.g.: all negative values) can be assigned in a `uint` and vice versa without potentially changing the meaning of the value.

Comment: Fair point, I suppose you'd have to distinguish between those cases then.

Answer (score -1):

A couple of approaches that might work:

1. Look at whether the types are implicitly castable as per the discussion [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119441/check-if-types-are-castable-subclasses)
2. Use reflection to compare the static MinValue and MaxValue properties of the numeric types.
3. Use a hard coded dictionary or lookup as suggested in previous answers. If the only set of types you care about is (uint, int, float, double, long, ulong) this is likely to be the easiest and most performant.

Comment: Yeah my original idea was to check against MinValue/MaxValue but I think it would be very costly, I was hoping I didn't know about something in .NET that could accomplish this sort of comparison quicker, oh well